# Homemade EVSE require UL/CSA/Other certification for insurance?

Tags: certification

In general, would an insurance company require a homemade electric vehicle charger to be approved by some recognized agency such as CSA or UL? I am in Canada.

I have designed and built a few electric vehicle chargers that I would like to give to my friends and family as the cost is MUCH much less than an equivalent commercial charger.

My worry is that, since it's not certified, an insurance company would refuse to pay out in the event of a fire whether or not the charger was the cause.

At the scale I am producing these things (may never make more than 10 in my life) it's obviously ridiculous to think of paying the 50K+ for a certification.

Before you go telling me off for how dangerous this sounds, I'll have you know that I am perfectly qualified to design and build this type of device, I just don't have the means to certify it.

Comment: What do bought chargers have in the way of certification?

Comment: the insurance company would certainly try to weasel their way out of paying

Comment: I got an EMI meter in A/m and V/m handheld that was cheap $50 and conducted ENI you just need a LISN To filter line and raise impedance then shunt with cap and current probe or sensor to self certify. Then surge test with a BEMF generator with Contactor to spark plug gapped to 4k or 5kV then RC filter to crest wave 10uS? And monitor current, document it and don’t tell them unless they ask. In MB any mods to CSA eg add LED can be approved by Hydro company for $xxx each

Comment: But that’s just to CYA in case of inspection.

Comment: ESA does special inspections.  You can call and ask them.  They maybe able to help.  They can certify for ESA and CSA.